# XSL-PDF error output

Tags: xsl-fo

```
<block>
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell padding="2mm" >
     <fo:block>____________________________________</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>

<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell padding="2mm" >
<fo:block>Parent's Signature</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
</block>
```

I want to have an ouput of :
    ***_*__*_*__*_*__** (\n)
    Parent's Signature

BUT

the output is :

__*_*__*_*_ (\n)
Parent's (\n)
Signature.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Is the cell wide enough to accommodate the text 'Parent's Signature'? Use e.g. a `background-color='green'` to see where the cell ends. You can specify `column-width` to force the column to be wide enough. 
It also looks like your table is incomplete, or is that just the sample? 
[example of table using column-width](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/obj_table-column.asp)

Comment: It is just a sample. that block of code will just add a blank line and under the line is a text "Parent's signature".